# only a part of "for" loop is working

Tags: bash

I have written a bash script, but I cannot understand what I am doing wrong. Here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR_LIST=('var_A' 'var_B' 'var_C')
FilePrefix='mystring_'
counter=1

for i in "${VAR_LIST[@]}"
do
        grep "$i" > "${FilePrefix}${counter}.tab.txt"
        counter=$((counter+1))
done <$1
```

Results: a file is created for each variable, but only the first one has data in it; the other files are empty. I have verified manually that each variable should return a few lines. The strange thing is that if I just do:

```
for i in "${VAR_LIST[@]}"
do 
 echo "$i"
done
```

I get the list of all the variables in `VAR_LIST`

Comment: You only read your input-file *once*. If you want to read it once *per loop iteration*, then you need to put the `<$1` inside the loop.

Comment: BTW, all-caps variable names are used for names with meaning to the OS or system, whereas POSIX guarantees that applications can use lowercase names without influencing or being influenced by specified shell and utilities; see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html. Since assigning a shell variable automatically updates any like-named environment variable, this applies even with no `export`s in play.

Comment: Thank you, @ruakh ; next time you may want to write your comment as an answer ;-)

Comment: BTW, is there any point to me writing up an answer (or an extension) that would read your input file once, and run all the `grep`s in parallel (with input copied from `tee`)? One could also do a single `awk` pass to write all the output files at once, even more efficiently than than the tee-to-multiple-greps approach.

Comment: Thank you, @CharlesDuffy, I would be interested in that. I really need to get more acquainted with the bash shell, and start studying it for real. So, if you like, that would be very kind of you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only opening the input file once -- which means that once the first `grep` has read it, there's nothing left for future ones to read.

Since bash doesn't have a way to call `seek()`, you'll need to re-open the file once per invocation:

```
for i in "${VAR_LIST[@]}"
do
        grep "$i" >"${FilePrefix}${counter}.tab.txt" <"$1"
        counter=$((counter+1))
done
```